# VB.NET LINQ join Distinct 2 tables

Tags: vb.net, linq, join, distinct, union

i have 2 datatables tables which have the same columns but with different data and some times there are rows the share the same ID

i want to join those to table where ID of some row in table2 doesn't exist in table1

```
so if i the following tables
ID Name
1  A
2  B
3  C

ID Name
5  D
1  A
2  B
3  C

the from joining would be

ID Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
5  D
```

here is what i tried

```
 Dim q = From e In tbl1.AsEnumerable Join r In tbl2.AsEnumerable On e.Field(Of Integer)("id") Equals r.Field(Of Integer)("id")
```

but no idea on how do i get this to a datatable

Comment: @MitchWheat update the question with my code

Comment: Seems like a UNION might be a better bet.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx

Comment: @MitchWheat but still, i am using `AsEnumerable` using union or join, how do i convert the data back to a datatable?!

Comment: It depends on your data source provider.

Comment: Do you have a requirement to return the data back as a `DataTable`?  Sometimes `IEnumerable<T>` will give you better performance and a reduced memory footprint.  You can easily extract the data from the tables using LINQ and do a `UNION` on the IEnumerable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ is not all that good in working with `DataTable` but you could do something like this:

```
Dim diff = tbl2.AsEnumerable().Except(tbl1.AsEnumerable(), New DataRowComparer())

Dim tbl = tbl1.Copy()
For Each dataRow As DataRow In diff
    tbl.ImportRow(dataRow)
Next
```

You need to create an `IEqualityComparer` to define how to compare `DataRow`s. I decided to compare only their `Id` value but you could compare every column in a similar manner:

```
Public Class DataRowComparer
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow)

    Public Function Equals(ByVal x As DataRow, ByVal y As DataRow) As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow).Equals
        Return CInt(x("Id")) = CInt(y("Id"))
    End Function

    Public Function GetHashCode(ByVal obj As DataRow) As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of DataRow).GetHashCode
        Return CInt(obj("Id")).GetHashCode()
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Actually, I think LINQ is just fine for working with `DataTable`.  The methods provided give you all the abilities of dealing with a POD.  What issues have you experienced?

Comment: @MauriceReeves I had in mind that it works on `IEnumerable` and requires additional work if you need the result in a `DataTable`. There's no `ToList` or `ToArray` equivalent for `DataTable`.

Comment: Got it.  I mean, the way I look at it, calling `ToEnumerable()` and then iterating the rows, filtering, using the predicates, etc is fairly painless.  There are cases where I don't use it, like if I just need to access a set of data one time, I might forgo IEnumerable<> and use the table directly, but at this point, any iteration, especially if I need to join to other datasets, I like to do via LINQ.